# SQL statement for a tricky 2 table query

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with SQL to much to get this working, table design is given,
so I can't change it.

**Table 1**

```
    username    usergroup   flag
    ----------------------------
    hans        unit1       0
    unit1       group1      NULL
    unit1       group2      NULL
    erwin       unit1       0
    jan         unit2       0
    jan         unit1       0
    unit2       group1      NULL
    unit2       group3      NULL
```

**Table 2**

```
    usergroup   roll_id
    --------------------
    group1      4   
    group2      5   
    group3      6
```

I need a statement that fetches the roll_ids for a given user name.

**Note:**

Users have flag 0.
Groups have flag NULL.

**Example:**

User jan is in unit1 and unit2, now every unit has one or more groups, stored in the same table.
So, before fetching the roll_id I need to know which groups to fetch?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What is tricky, what was wrong with your approach that you didnt show?

Comment: join the two tables? SELECT roll_id FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.usergroup = table2.username AND table1.username = 'someUsername'?

Comment: Is `usename` in table2 equals `usergroup` in table1?

Comment: @Jens based on the values and "tricky 2 table query", I guess that would be Yes? I don't see how is it tricky though.

Comment: @Gosu Then it is very bad naming.

Comment: as an example, user jan is in unit1 and unit2, both units have different groups, which are stored in the same table, the flag 0 is a user, the flag NULL a group.

Comment: `"a statement that fetches the roll_ids for a given username"` - According to the data, that information is stored entirely in the second table.  `SELECT roll_id FROM [table 2] WHERE username = 'some value'`  What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.roll_id FROM table1 t1a, table1 t1b, table2 t2
WHERE t1a.flag = 0 AND t1a.usergroup = t1b.username
AND t1b.usergroup =  t2.username AND t1a.username = 'someUsername'
```

2 copies of table1 to find the actual 'usergroup' for an user? and join it with table2?

Answer (score 0):

A simple JOIN should do it. If I understand your requirements correctly, this should work:

`SELECT table2.roll_id FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON (table2.username = table1.usergroup)
WHERE table1.username="enter a username here"`

I assumed your schema was correct and that table1.usergroup matches up with table2.username. You might want to consider renaming your column names for clarity.